# Laravel Liveiwre Auto converting .iges ie Mime type of model/iges to text/plain while uploading it on temp

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

We are trying to upload the .ges ie Mime type of models/iges format in Laravel Livewire, but when it uploads to temp itself its converts the format as text/plain rather the original format.

We need to get the exact file format instead of the wrong one

```html
<form wire:submit.prevent="save">

    @if ($photo)
        Photo Preview:
        <img src="{{ $photo->temporaryUrl() }}">
    @endif
 
    <input type="file" wire:model="photo">
 
    @error('photo') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
 
    <button type="submit">Save Photo</button>

</form>
```

We will be using the above code to attach the files - when we preview the .iges file it shows text/plain mime type even in the temp path the file is stored in the .txt format

Comment: Please show the relevant code, the request is too vague